# Sort a collection based on the number of Characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection called as SheetNameCol which contains Sheet Names such as Act Collection, Act, Les.

I have another collection called as HeaderRowCol which contains Header Rows 7,8,9.

The Sheet Names from the SheetNameCol and Header Rows from the HeaderRow are related.

```
index   SheetNameCol      HeaderRowCol
1        Act Collection    7
2        Act               8
3        Les               9
```

I want to sort the SheetNameCol based on the number of characters in the Sheet Names.

So my expected output will be :-

```
index   SheetNameCol      HeaderRowCol
1       Act                 8
2       Les                 9
3       Act Collection      7
```

How do I do this more efficiently? Please kindly note that the HeaderRowCol has also changed based on the Change in the SheetNameCol.

I know, I have to create a new collection that has the number of characters to do this easier - So, I have started that like this -

```
Set SortSheetNameCol = New Collection

    For l = 1 To SheetNameCol.Count

    ReqLength = Len(SheetNameCol(l))

    SortSheetNameCol.Add ReqLength

    Next
```

But I am struck for a clear cut logic here.

Comment: Struck by what? Sorry! What happens for items of the same length?

Comment: @QHarr. Updated the Question now. The items of same length can  be next to each other (no rules of which one to go on top/down) but the Header Rows for the assigned sheet names needs to stay related. I am struck for a clear cut logic to proceed from here being a beginner with Collections and Arrays.

Comment: Can you have it in the sheet with an additional column for len? And sort that? Then read that into an array so is already sorted? You are going to have to maintain the list somehow so that would seem quite easy. 1 line of code pretty much to read array in from sheet.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: @QHarr  The problem here is - I am working on other's code which are connected to so many pieces. So, I would rather prefer building something new and take the value from that.

Comment: So  SheetNameCol      HeaderRowCol are both collections and are currently related by index ? so 1 goes with 1 etc....

Comment: @QHarr Yes. You are right !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I meant by using a worksheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim SheetNameCol As Collection
    Dim HeaderRowCol As Collection

    Set SheetNameCol = New Collection
    Set HeaderRowCol = New Collection

    SheetNameCol.Add "Act Collection"
    SheetNameCol.Add "Act"
    SheetNameCol.Add "Les"

    HeaderRowCol.Add 7
    HeaderRowCol.Add 8
    HeaderRowCol.Add 9

    If SheetNameCol.Count <> HeaderRowCol.Count Then
        MsgBox "Collections are of unequal item length"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim arr()
    ReDim arr(0 To SheetNameCol.Count - 1, 0 To 2)
    Dim currItem As Long
    Dim itemCount As Long

    itemCount = SheetNameCol.Count

    For currItem = 1 To itemCount

        arr(currItem - 1, 0) = Len(SheetNameCol(currItem))
        arr(currItem - 1, 1) = SheetNameCol(currItem)
        arr(currItem - 1, 2) = HeaderRowCol(currItem)

    Next currItem

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2) + 1)

        .Value = arr
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Cells(1, 2), Order2:=xlAscending
        arr = .Value

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ws.Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set SheetNameCol = New Collection
    Set HeaderRowCol = New Collection

    For currItem = 1 To itemCount

        SheetNameCol.Add arr(currItem, 2)
        HeaderRowCol.Add arr(currItem, 3)

    Next currItem

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could use `SortedList` object to exploit its built-in autosorting and write a helper sub:

```
Sub SortCollections(coll1 As Collection, coll2 As Collection)
    Dim iItem  As Long

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.Sortedlist")
        For iItem = 1 To coll1.Count
            .Add Len(coll1.Item(iItem)) & "|" & coll1.Item(iItem), coll2.Item(iItem)
        Next
        Set coll1 = New Collection
        Set coll2 = New Collection
        For iItem = .Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            coll1.Add Split(.getkey(iItem), "|")(1)
            coll2.Add .GetByIndex(iItem)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

here's an example of how to use it

```
Sub Example()        
    Dim SheetNameCol As New Collection
    Dim HeaderRowCol As New Collection

    ' fill SheetNameCol 
    With SheetNameCol
        .Add "Act Collection"
        .Add "Act"
        .Add "Les"
    End With

    ' fill HeaderRowCol
    With HeaderRowCol
        .Add 7
        .Add 8
        .Add 9
    End With

    Dim iItem  As Long

    'list SheetNameCol and HeaderRowCol before sorting
    For iItem = 1 To SheetNameCol.Count
        MsgBox SheetNameCol.Item(iItem) & ", " & HeaderRowCol.Item(iItem)
    Next

    SortCollections SheetNameCol, HeaderRowCol ' sort

    'list SheetNameCol and HeaderRowCol after sorting
    For iItem = 1 To SheetNameCol.Count
        MsgBox SheetNameCol.Item(iItem) & ", " & HeaderRowCol.Item(iItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer is late, here's another solution more in line with your original approach.  This code does not rely upon Excel:

```
Private Sub cmdSort_Click()
   Dim SortSheetNameCol As Collection
   Dim SortHeaderRowCol As Collection
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

   Set SortSheetNameCol = New Collection
   Set SortHeaderRowCol = New Collection

   For i = 1 To SheetNameCol.Count
       For j = 1 To SortSheetNameCol.Count
           If Len(SheetNameCol(i)) < Len(SortSheetNameCol(j)) Then
               SortSheetNameCol.Add SheetNameCol(i), , j
               SortHeaderRowCol.Add HeaderRowCol(i), , j
               Exit For
           End If
       Next

       If j - 1 = SortSheetNameCol.Count Then
          SortSheetNameCol.Add SheetNameCol(i)
          SortHeaderRowCol.Add HeaderRowCol(i)
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```